# CORS configurations in Django not working in production

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, cors, django-cors-headers

I am working on a chat application with Django at the back-end and React at the front-end.
Both are hosted on separate domains on vercel.

I have added the CORS configurations in the back-end but they don't seem to be working in the production.

Following are the CORS configs done in Django:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.vercel.app'] 

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['https://texter-frontend.vercel.app',]
```

Here is one of the requests from the front-end:

```
const backendServerEndpoint = 'https://texter-backend-jp24ejwc8-sourav-pys-projects.vercel.app';
const requestData = {
    'phoneNumber' : phoneNumber
};           

fetch(backendServerEndpoint + '/auth/sendotp/',{
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: "cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",        
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestData), 
})        
        
.then(
    response => {
        if(response.status === 200){        
            setOtpSent(true);            
            response.json()        
            .then(       
                responseData => {            
                    console.log(responseData);                
                    if(responseData.newProfile){            
                        console.log("It is a new profile!!!");                
                        setNewProfile(true);            
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    } 
)
.catch(
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
)
```

This is the error that I am getting in the console:

Access to fetch at 'https://texter-backend-jp24ejwc8-sourav-pys-projects.vercel.app/auth/sendotp/' from origin 'https://texter-frontend.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

P.S: When I deploy it on my local by replacing the vercel URLs with localhost/127.0.0.1, it is working fine.

https://github.com/sourav-py/texter_backend
https://github.com/sourav-py/texter_frontend

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], looking at your code you've actually set up CORS correctly. I tried accessing your website and the problem basically is your backend is returning a 401 response when you hit that URL.

Comment: List `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` first in `MIDDLEWARE`. Also, you need to list `Content-Type` as an allowed header.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Hi, I have added a test route, will add the same in the above problem description in some time.

Comment: @jub0bs Hi, I followed these steps but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Difficult for me/us to help you further without a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of the server-side code, I think.

Comment: Try with CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ['texter-frontend.vercel.app']